# Running php vendor/bin/phoenix migrate inside a docker container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to run `$ php vendor/bin/phoenix migrate` (database migration) from inside the docker container. I'm wondering where to put it inside my `docker-compose.yml` or `Dockerfile`. I have had no success trying and I'm beginning to feel like an idiot.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  web: 
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    working_dir: /app
    command: sh -c 'php vendor/bin/phoenix migrate'
    links:
      - php
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - 33006:3306
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
  composer:
    image: composer/composer
    command: composer dump-autoload
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

And here is my `Dockerfile`

```sh
FROM php:8-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
```

The response I get in my `console` with above configuration is

```sh
...
little-php-framework-mariadb-1   | 2022-02-22  6:48:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220222  6:48:02
little-php-framework-mariadb-1   | 2022-02-22  6:48:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
little-php-framework-mariadb-1   | 2022-02-22  6:48:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
little-php-framework-mariadb-1   | 2022-02-22  6:48:02 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@f82446e71daf' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
little-php-framework-mariadb-1   | 2022-02-22  6:48:02 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
little-php-framework-mariadb-1   | Version: '10.6.5-MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
little-php-framework-php-1 exited with code 255
little-php-framework-web-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
little-php-framework-web-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
little-php-framework-web-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
little-php-framework-web-1       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
little-php-framework-web-1       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
little-php-framework-web-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
little-php-framework-web-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
little-php-framework-web-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
little-php-framework-web-1       | 2022/02/22 06:48:02 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
little-php-framework-web-1       | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
little-php-framework-web-1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you must expose and run php-fpm in `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Hi Lee, I tried this but it produced the same error. Can you tell me why you thoughtthis would work because maybe I missed something.

Comment: can you show me your `./default.conf` of nginx config?

Comment: I made a JsFiddle for readability https://jsfiddle.net/rvrbk/L2ueg46k/1/

Comment: I made a Dockerfile for you. Networks has been added. build and force-recreate container again. https://gist.github.com/ohmygodvt95/b3103e422fc141c4a5288f33a6402144